# Failed to start PostgreSQL Cluster 10-main when booting

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, pid, boot

when I try to boot Ubuntu, it never finishes the boot process because it appears the message "Failed to start PostgreSQL Cluster 10-main." I also get the same message with 9.5-main. But lets focus on 10.

When I execute:

```
systemctl status postgresql@10-main.service
```

I get the following message:

```
postgresql@10-main.service - PostgreSQL Cluster 10-main
  Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service; indirect; vendor preset: enabled)
  Active: failed (Result: protocol) since Wed 2020-02-19 17:57:22 CET; 30 min ago
 Process: 1602 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect 10-main start (code_exited, status=1/FAILURE)
PC_info systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL Cluster 10-main...
PC_info postgresql@10-main[1602]: Error: /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_ctl /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_ctl start -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main -l /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-19-main.log -s -o -c config_file="/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf" exit with status 1:
PC_info systemd[1]: postgresql@10-main.service: Can't open PID file /var/run/postgresql/10-main.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
PC_info systemd[1]: postgresql@10-main.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
PC_info systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL Cluster 10-main.
```

PC_info is information about my computer (user, date..) not relevant

I got this error from one day to an other without touching anything related to Database Servers.
I tried to fix it by my self but nothing worked

Writing the command

```
service postgresql@10-main start
```

I get

```
Job for postgresql@10-main.service failed because the service did not take the steps required by its unit configuration
See "systemctl status postgresql@10-main.service" and "journalctl -xe"  for details.
```

Running this two command I get the message from the beginning.

Anyone has an idea of what is happening? How I can fix it?

Comment: I have the same error and I'm still not really sure what the cause is. My temporary solution was trying out the command mentioned in the Systemd error message:

`/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_ctl start -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main -l /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-19-main.log -s -o -c config_file="/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf"`

To make it a valid command you actually need to enclose the last part in single quotes (`-c config_file="/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf"`) so that it gets passed correctly to the postgres command (see `pgctl` man page).

Answer (score 24):

I had same issue, I followed below steps,

Error status :

- `pg_lsclusters`

```
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file

10  main    5432 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/10/main
/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log
```

Applied Solution :

- `sudo chmod 700 -R /var/lib/postgresql/10/main`
- `sudo -i -u postgres`
- `postgres@abc:~$ /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_ctl restart -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main`

After Solution status :

- `pg_lsclusters`

```
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
 
10  main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/10/main
/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log
```

Comment: OMG I wish i could give you a hug sir. thank you so much.

Comment: Yeap!! Absolutely worked for me postgres 10

Comment: Thanks. Last command showed to me, that the issue was "No space left on device".

So, cleaning space and restarting service helped.

Comment: second time in a week this saved my systemd setup after upgrade of cluster

Comment: I also apt remove the older postgresql version to fix an error: postgresql@14-main.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.

Comment: Please explain why this solves the problem!! Also, if possible, what is the root cause of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me in Postgres 15 because of insufficient free space. Cleaning up my PC solved this issue.

Comment: This is indeed a splendid answer.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned by @gruentee in comment above,

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_ctl restart -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main -l /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log -s -o  '-c config_file="/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf"'
```

started the postgresSql DB. Dont forget to

```
sudo -i -u postgres
```

before issuing above command

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same challenge, I try a lot of methods but none work for me till I try these commands below

```
sudo apt-get -y install postgresql
sudo systemctl start postgresql@15-main.service
pg_lsclusters
```

then everything started working fine, but please the version of postgresql i'm using is 15 that's you are seeing 15 in the second command so in your case you substitute it with the version you are using

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because I had (stupidly) once taken ownership ( `chown luc:luc` ) over whole */var/log/* folder. It had the effect to make file */var/log/postgresql/postgresql-14-main.log* unaccessible during boot, causing the PostgreSQL startup fail.

Restoring ownership of /var/log/ folder to root ( `# chown -R root:root /var/log/*` ) fixed the issue.